# Interpolate Twig variable/attribute inside value of another Twig attribute definition

Tags: object, twig, interpolation, templating, templating-engine

Take the following example structure:

```
{% set paths = {
                   ...
                   'js': {
                           ...
                           'jquery': {
                                      'version': '1.7.2',
                                      'cdn': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/{{paths.js.jquery.version}}/jquery.min.js',
                                      'fallback': ....
                                      }
                          }
               }
%}
```

To access, I would normally use something like:

```
 <script src="{{paths.js.jquery.cdn}}"></script>
```

---

#### The problem:

The interpolated variable isn't recognized, you will get something like `...libs/jquery/%7B%7B%paths.js/jquery.version7D%7D/jquery.min.js...`.

I've tried:

- `'a': 'text{{b}}text'`,
- `'a': {{ ('text' ~ b ~ 'text') }}`,
- `'a': "{{ ('text' ~ b ~ 'text') }}"`,
- `'a': "{{ (['text', b, 'text'] | join }}"`,
- `'a': "{{ (['text', {{b}}, 'text'] | join }}"`
- And more I've forgotten

---

#### I'm aware of attribute()

There's not a lot of documentation on it, but from what I see, it would have to be something like this:

```
attribute(paths, attribute(js, attribute(jquery, cdn)))
```

It would be fine for one level, but not an arbitrary level of depth. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding `attribute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'a': ('text' ~ b ~ 'text'`) is actually correct, but there cannot be curly braces around the expression (because we're already inside an expression, a variable definition).

The correct way:

```
{% set paths = {
                   ...
                   'js': {
                           ...
                           'jquery': {
                                      'version': '1.7.2',
                                      'cdn': ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' ~ paths.js.jquery.version ~ '/jquery.min.js'),
                                      'fallback': ....
                                      }
                          }
               }
%}
```

---

But there is simple design mistake here; when the renderer/parser comes to the `cdn` attribute definition, `paths` isn't set yet. One possible way to get around this is to declare another variable first;

```
{% set params=  {
                   'jqueryversion': '1.7.2'
                }
%}

{% set paths = {
                   ...
                   'js': {
                           ...
                           'jquery': {
                                      'cdn': ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' ~ params.jqueryversion ~ '/jquery.min.js'),
                                      'fallback': ....
                                      }
                          }
               }
%}
```

Obviously if `paths.js.jquery.cdn` is only going to be used once then just hardcode the *parent* variable's value where you need it and interpolate the *child* variable:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/{{params.jqueryversion}}/jquery.min.js"></script>
```